# Redirect after login AngularJS Meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router, angular-meteor

I'm trying to redirect after login to a specific page in Meteor using AngularJS. But somehow it is not working. After login Meteor.user() is returning null. Because of this every time it is routing to messages page only. I have seen this example from one of the forums and developed on top of that.

```
angular.module("jaarvis").run(["$rootScope", "$state", "$meteor", function($rootScope, $state, $meteor) {

   $meteor.autorun($rootScope, function(){
      if (! Meteor.user()) {
        console.log('user');
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
          console.log('loggingIn ' + Meteor.user()); -- returning null
          if(Meteor.user()) {
            $state.go('onlineusers');
          } else {
            //On login
            $state.go("messages");
          }
        }
        else{
          console.log('login');
          $state.go('login');
        }
      }
     });

}]);
```

Routes declared as below.

```
angular.module('jaarvis').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',

    function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
          url: '/login',
          templateUrl: 'login.ng.html',
          controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .state('onlineusers',{
          url: '/onlineusers',
          templateUrl: 'client/onlineusers/onlineusers.ng.html',
          controller: 'OnlineUsersCtrl'
        })
        .state('messages', {
          url: '/messages',
          templateUrl: 'client/chats.ng.html',
          controller: 'ChatCtrl'
        })
        });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/messages");
    }]);
```

Logging using below snippet of code.

```
<meteor-include src="loginButtons"></meteor-include>
```

Comment: Are you using your own custom login using angular-meteor? They return a promise which would allow you to redirect `$meteor.loginWithPassword(username, pass).then(function() { $state.go('wherever')});`

Comment: @Tj Gienger I tried using custom login but callback method is not calling. $meteor.loginWithFacebook({requestPermissions: ['email']}).then(function(){
       console.log('Login success');
       }, function(err){
        console.log('Login error - ', err);
     });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Michael is probably right about the root cause of the problem, but I think that a better alternative is provided by the the [authentication methods](http://angular-meteor.com/api/auth) of Angular-Meteor.

What you are going to want to do is to force the resolution of a promise on the route. From the Angular-Meteor docs (i.e. a general example...):

```
// In route config ('ui-router' in the example, but works with 'ngRoute' the same way)
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'client/views/home.ng.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
    resolve: {
      "currentUser": ["$meteor", function($meteor){
        return $meteor.waitForUser();
      }]
    }
});
```

Your specific code would look something like:

```
angular.module('jaarvis').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider, $locationProvider){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $stateProvider
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'login.ng.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    })
    .state('onlineusers',{
      url: '/onlineusers',
      templateUrl: 'client/onlineusers/onlineusers.ng.html',
      controller: 'OnlineUsersCtrl',
      resolve: {
          "currentUser": ["$meteor", function($meteor){
               return $meteor.waitForUser();
           }]
      }
    })
    .state('messages', {
      url: '/messages',
      templateUrl: 'client/chats.ng.html',
      controller: 'ChatCtrl',
      resolve: {
          "currentUser": ["$meteor", function($meteor){
               return $meteor.waitForUser();
           }]
      }
    })
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/messages");
}]);
```

And then on your `ChatCtrl` and `OnlineUsersCtrl` controllers, you would add `currentUser` as one of the variables to inject, like:

```
angular.module("rootModule").controller("ChatCtrl", ["$scope", "$meteor", ..., 
    function($scope, $meteor, ..., "currentUser"){
        console.log(currentUser) // SHOULD PRINT WHAT YOU WANT
    }
]);
```

You might also want to consider the `$meteor.requireUser()` promise as well, and then send the user back to the login page if the promise gets rejected. All of this is documented very well on the angular-meteor website.

Good luck!

Comment: I tried to inject currentUser but it is throwing below exception.   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: currentUserProvider <- currentUser <- LoginCtrl

Comment: Sorry you are right, I have a typo that I will edit in my answer. In sum: don't inject 'currentUser' -- the UI router resolve already takes care of it for us, just place it as a variable in the scope function. 

Should be:

`angular.module("rootModule").controller("ChatCtrl", ["$scope", "$meteor", function($scope, $meteor, ..., "currentUser"){
    console.log(currentUser) // SHOULD PRINT WHAT YOU WANT
}]`

Remove the dependency injection of `currentUser` -- resolve already takes care of this for us

Comment: I used some of your suggestions and improved my application. In above example currentUser is null or undefined most of the cases. I used Accounts.onLogin() functionality to redirect intended page. Thanks for your valuable time and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the user object hasn't loaded yet. You can try:

```
if ( Meteor.userId() ) ...
```

instead

Comment: I can try this approach but I think need to get user object once again and check isAdmin parameter.

Comment: I'm fairly new to meteor but I'm so confused about `Meteor.userId()` because while it works for me perfectly in my local environment, it's routinely `undefined` when I attempt to perform the same actions on my heroku production server.

Comment: `Meteor.userId()` is used on the client whereas in server methods and publications you use `this.userId`.